# Empty desktop after installing proprietary Nvidia drivers on 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I have a new machine with an Nvidia Tesla P100 card. To install the proprietary Nvidia driver I did the following:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
apt-get install nvidia-410
```

That installation seemed to work fine. After rebooting the system, however, I have the following issue:

- When I use the normal Intel driver (via `prime-select intel`), then I can boot normally into the Ubuntu desktop and use it as usual, but then I cannot make use of the Nvidia driver (as it is not being used, makes sense).
- When I use the Nvidia driver (via `prime-select nvidia`), then I cannot use the machine at all, because after rebooting and logging into the Ubuntu desktop as usual, that desktop remains "empty" (i.e. no menu bar, no windows, no nothing, not even the mouse cursor, just the desktop background image).

Of couse I want to use the Nvidia driver. It seems the problem might be somehow related to some Ubuntu or X tool (like Unity) or whatever that does not work correctly with the Nvidia driver.

Any ideas?

PS, one more note: The monitor is connected to the onboard graphics port, the Tesla card does not have any cable interface, neither HDMI nor DVI. But that is fine, I need the Tesla card only for background jobs and calculations, like for TensorFlow. But I do need the Nvidia driver working in order to make use of the Tesla card ...